Firebase Realtime Database observe method returns Null after starting a search query
Here's my service:
final class UserDataService: Sendable {

    static let shared = UserDataService()

    private let databaseRef = Database.database(url: "https://catogram-58487-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app").reference()

    func observeUser(with uid: String) {
        let path = "Users/" + uid
        let query = databaseRef.child(path)
        query.observe(.value) { snapshot in
            print("\nObserved path: ", path)
            print("Observed user snapshot: ", snapshot)
        }
    }

    func searchUserWith(username: String) async throws {
        let usersRef = self.databaseRef.child("Users")
        let startString = username
        let endString = username + "\\uf8ff"
        let query = usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "username")
            .queryStarting(atValue: startString)
            .queryEnding(atValue: endString)
        let data = try await query.getData()
    // Doesn't do anything cause it's unrelated. 
    // Just firing this query will trigger the issue.
    }
}

In observeUser method you can see two print statements, here are their output on the startup of the app:
Observed path:  Users/Oi8HDhspOWYsgs4gE9zMnbkK65j2
Observed user snapshot:  Snap (Oi8HDhspOWYsgs4gE9zMnbkK65j2) {
    birthday = "12/11/2016";
    email = "testuseremail@gmail.com";
    gender = Male;
    joinDate = "1718197814.370859";
    name = "Test User";
    posts = 0;
    userID = Oi8HDhspOWYsgs4gE9zMnbkK65j2;
    username = testusername02;
}

The observeUser method is constantly observing user data at specified path and returns data every time there's any change detected. Somehow the query from searchUserWith makes observeUser return Null as if the data at the path it was observing got deleted.
Here's what observeUser prints out when the search query is fired:
Observed path:  Users/Oi8HDhspOWYsgs4gE9zMnbkK65j2
Observed user snapshot:  Snap (Oi8HDhspOWYsgs4gE9zMnbkK65j2) <null>

And no matter what I do, Firebase's .observe or .getData() methods will be returning Null for this path until I restart the app.
I made a separate "observe" UIButton so that I can repeatedly trigger observe method after search query and see its output, it always returns Null after performing the search.
The interesting thing is, that if the search result will include currently logged-in user (the one that I'm observing), the app will continue to function normally.
Here are my security rules for Users node:
"rules": {
    "Users": {
      ".indexOn": "username",
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true,
    },
}

And here's other code I used to create Minimal Reproducible Example:
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var searchButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("Search", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        button.tintColor = .white
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        button.layer.cornerCurve = .continuous
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(triggerSearchMethod), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    private lazy var observe: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("Observe", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        button.tintColor = .white
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        button.layer.cornerCurve = .continuous
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(observeUser), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        setupCurrentUserListener()
        setupSearchButton()
        setupObserveButton()
    }

    private func setupSearchButton() {
        view.addSubview(searchButton)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            searchButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            searchButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70),
            searchButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            searchButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    private func setupObserveButton() {
        view.addSubview(observe)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            observe.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            observe.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            observe.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70),
            observe.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        ])
    }

   private func setupCurrentUserListener() {
        let currentUserID = AuthenticationService.shared.getCurrentUserUID()
        UserDataService.shared.observeUser(with: currentUserID)
    }

    @objc func triggerSearchMethod() {
        print("search tapped")
        Task {
            try await UserDataService.shared.searchUserWith(username: "Username")
        }
    }

    @objc func observeUser() {
        setupCurrentUserListener()
    }
}



That's quite a bit of code for us to parse through. Doing some basic troubleshooting will help us to help you. Add a breakpoint and step through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected. Then update the question as to what line that is; the expected result and the actual result.

@Jay the unexpected behaviour is that after triggering searchUserWith(username: String) method, the observeUser method in other part of the app will callback with Null. I've tried stepping over these methods with breakpoints but it's mostly a bunch of firebase gibberish that I cannot judge what is expected and what's not.

One issue, and perhaps it's terminology, is that Firebase calls are asynchronous - they do not return values like a synchronous call. Here's troubleshooting. 1) What is the expected result of query.observe(.value) { snapshot in? The answer is: snapshot should contain data 2) Add a line immediately following that line print(snapshot) and run the code. What is the expected result? To print the snapshot to console. 3) Add a breakpoint to that line, run the code. Does the code stop at that line? Yes? Continue to next line. What prints to console? No: place the breakpoint earlier in the code.

Additional troubleshooting: Is the path correct? What does this let path = DatabaseKeys.users + uid resolve to, is it what you expect? Did you verify there is data at that path? That's the kind of information we need to help. If there's too much code, the question is less likely to get an answer - see How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

@Jay thank you for taking your time to explain to me what info I should add. I've edited my question and reworked my MRE. I hope this is enough now and will help others to understand the issue.

If you know the username, why do a resource heavy query when you can just read the child node directly?  e.g. the node name is the username which could be read at /Users/userid instead of generating a query on the entire Users node for the same thing. Just curious. Also - * trigger the searchUserWith method those print statements in observeUser* - the searchUserWith doesn't call observeUser so how would the print statements output to console?

@Jay "the searchUserWith doesn't call observeUser so how would the print statements output to console?" – that's what I'm trying to figure out, it doesn't call the observeUser method directly but somehow affects it.
The observeUser method is constantly observing user data at specified path and returns data every time there's any change detected. Somehow the query from ''searchUserWithmakesobserveUser`` return Null as if the data at the path it was observing got deleted.

@Jay "If you know the username, why do a resource heavy query" – this is an intended behaviour, this method is used for looking up other users of the app, you may not know the entire username but if you start entering first three letters it'll show users with usernames that start with those letters, the more letters the more precise and narrower the search result is. I hope it explains it. If you know a better way to do this I'd love to read on it.

I see. One issue is that if the user types upper case, it will not find a match, so everything needs to be converted to lower. And yes, there are additional solutions and some suggestions. See my answer to this question as well as this question. Your solution to use ~ is the right idea, just not high enough in the ascii table to cover all cases.

@Jay I removed all unnecessary code and updated the question with the structure of Users node and security rules, maybe this can be helpful, please take a look. The Service methods are now only firing the queries without processing the result, the issue persists, it doesn't make any sense to me. And trying to google similar issues doesn't help. It's like I'm the only one who has faces this issue.

The question is more clear but there are still a number of issues. 1) Don't include path separators like here "Users/" just use "Users" (not an error, but best practice). 2) This "\(username)~" is not the proper way to search per above. 3) func searchUserWith doesn't do anything with the data so it will just silently go out of scope 4) "Username" will never be found because it contains uppercase characters and those are not accounted for (per above) 5) I would set the read/write Rules to true to eliminate that as a potential issue.

@Jay 1) Removed path separators where not needed. 2) Adopted a proper way to search from the answers to questions you've shared above. 3) It doesn't do anything because I wanted to exclude any unrelatable code to the issue. 4) I will create another node for this specific query with lowercased usernames in the future. 5) I've set read/write rules to true and the issue still persists. 
When using "\uf8ff" instead of "~" some users can only be found when entering their full username. For some of them only half of the username is enough but still is too many characters to find a user.

@Jay I've created a separate node with only lowercased usernames, now I'm querying over it to search for users. I have one issue though: using the "\uf8ff" character instead of "~" at the end of String will result in inconsistent results. Most of the time it will find user only if the username is fully entered, no partial results, for some entering half of the username is enough.
By creating this separate node I eliminated the main issue discussed in this question, but that's only because I'm no longer querying over the "Users" node, a subnode of which is being observed.

I am seeing a possible issue with "\uf8ff" which I've not seen before (it's been working for years so I am investigating. In the meantime change this let endString = username + "\\uf8ff" to this let endString = username +  "\u{F8FF}" and try it

@Jay The "\u{F8FF}" works perfectly, thanks. I'd love to read about why do we need to use these characters in queries and how exactly it works, but I'm not sure what to google. Could you give me a few keywords I should use to look this up?

The \u{n} is an an arbitrary Unicode scalar value, where n is a 1–8 digit hexadecimal number. So a char $ would be this "\u{24}" for example. In current Swift, hex values must be formatted unicode \u{n}. This {} is more specific to swift than say, JSON as they do not have the same syntax.

Things have changed a bit over the last few years in regards to syntax.
In summary, the code in the question is attempting a partial string query which Firebase doesn't directly support. The solution is to generate a query between two strings, inclusive, starting at whatever the input string is and ending with the same string terminated by a character very high in the unicode table.
For example, if the user was querying for all strings starting with Ap the query would be queryStarting(Ap) ... queryEnding(Ap{f8ff}) where f8ff is a unicode scaler high in the unicode table. That would result in
Apatite
Apex
Apple
Application
etc

But this does not work
let startString = username
let endString = username + "\\uf8ff"

the unicode scaler character needs to be formatted "\u{F8FF}"
let startString = username
let endString = username + "\u{F8FF}"

Note that this 'issue' is purely language syntax related. In Swift:
let x = "\\uf8ff"
let y = "\u{F8FF}"
print(x)
print(y)

results in
\uf8ff


Whereas "\uf8ff" is correct syntax for json and I believe applies to Android as well.
If you really want to use a json formatted unicode scaler, this solution works.
let jsonString = #"{ "unicodeChar" : "\uf8ff"}"#
let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
if let data = data { let dict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: String]
    print(dict?["unicodeChar"] ?? "")
}

